# Group-concat get an error in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

my code is

```
select group_concat(distinct v.visitor_datetime  from dates table separator '|')
```

and I got an error that
invaild syntax in mysql

Comment: are you sure you want to do group concat all values without doing group by a column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select group_concat(distinct v.visitor_datetime   separator '|')from dates table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT visitor_datetime separator '|') FROM dates`

Notice that I left out the `v` before `visitor_datetime` and the table alias `table`.